# Angularjs: What exactly ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end are

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just would like to know what exactly `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` are?
And why we should use them instead of `ng-repeat`? 
I mean what is the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that sometimes is better to repeat a series of elements instead of just one parent element.

In this case you can get repeat item looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat-start>ITEM HEADER</div>
CONTENT
<div ng-repeat-end>ITEM FOOTER</div>
```

instead of one root element:

```
<div ng-repeat>CONTENT</div>
```